# How do I use 31 subnet on point to point link?

Tags: mask, subnet

I want to use 31 subnet on point to point links so that I can save ip address. But what can I do, will I modify the linux kernel?

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible duplicate of other (better, longer) answers, but you need to use the key words RFC3021, if using linux there is even a setting to use a /32 pointopoint, but then you need to specify the peerip.